# How do you drain a dataflow job through the gcloud api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to drain a running dataflow job through the the gcloud api? Specifically is there a python implementation of this, or documentation of the request structure so that it can be implemented? It would be nice to be able to automate draining, and reconfiguring dataflow streaming jobs without the use of the cli.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to drain a running dataflow via [Rest Update API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update) thanks to [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41662247/4786620).

Body for POST Update request:

> {
>     "requestedState": "JOB_STATE_DRAINING"
>   }

Comment: Hi @Thierry Falvo. I want to run batch jobs in Dataflow for processing small datasets that may get huge someday. In batch mode, dataflow needs to start VMs before running the job, which is really unfortunate for small datasets processing. But seeing the possibility as running a streaming job and then draining the job later may be a good thing to do. Do you think this would help?

Comment: Hi @d4nielfr4nco, really I'm not sure. Dataflow in stream or batch mode will consume VMs behind the scene, and you'll be billed on a vCPU / hour basis. Normally you should don't care about VM startup, but final cost is the main important thing. With Apache Beam v2, pub/sub pipeline is only available in streaming mode. So my concern was how to optimize cost of stream mode, because it won't scale to 0. (you'll be billed even if no message on topic). So it's why I was looking for a way to start and drain it a few times per day for example... Hope my comment is clear and relevant ;-)

Comment: See also my question "Can Cloud Dataflow streaming job scale to zero?" : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292952/can-cloud-dataflow-streaming-job-scale-to-zero

Comment: Yeah, I think cost will be more important for my particular use case, so batch is the way to go. Thanks a lot.