# How to kill a Beam Dataflow job programmatically from workers

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to kill an Apache Beam job programmatically from worker nodes using Java Beam SDK.
Ideally I would like this solution to be runner independent, but even a DataflowRunner specific solution would do.

I don't want to use shutdown hooks, I am looking for something that is supported by the beam API.

The closest I have found to what I want is `org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.MonitoringUtil::getGcloudCancelCommand`. However, this just returns a String with the command that needs to run to cancel the job. It is not cancelling the job from within the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminating (draining) the job from within DoFn.ProcessElement:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.api.services.dataflow.model.Job;

import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowClient;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;

class DrainDoFn<S, T> extends DoFn<S, T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext pc) throws IOException {
        PipelineOptions options = pc.getPipelineOptions();
        DataflowPipelineOptions dpOptions =
            options.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

        DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions dwhOptions =
            options.as(DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions.class);

        String jobId = dwhOptions.getJobId();
        DataflowClient dataflowClient = DataflowClient.create(dpOptions);
        Job jobDescription = dataflowClient.getJob(jobId);
        jobDescription.setRequestedState("JOB_STATE_DRAINING");
        dataflowClient.updateJob(jobId, jobDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I used this and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible commands you can use to stop Dataflow job: `Cancel` and `Drain`. You can do so by issuing a command using either the Dataflow Monitoring Interface or the Dataflow Command-line Interface. Please, refer to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/stopping-a-pipeline).

Additionally you can check [REST update API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update) `projects.locations.jobs.update` to update the state of an existing Dataflow job.

Use Rest Update method, with this body, find more in [Google Developers guide](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dataflow/v1b3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Dataflow_1_1v1b3_1_1Data_1_1Job.html#ac48350bab5eaec345a4bcc167bbb313e):

```
{ "requestedState": "JOB_STATE_DRAINING" }
```

Additionally, I really recommend you to look for [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661470/how-do-i-drain-a-pipeline-from-within-another-pipeline/41662247#41662247) thread. I hope it helps.

Comment: Muscat, thanks for your answer. The [link you included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661470/how-do-i-drain-a-pipeline-from-within-another-pipeline/41662247#41662247) pointed me to the right direction. It didn't answer my question, though, so I up-voted it, but I cannot accept it as an answer.