# How to cancel a GCP Dataflow job programmingly using Beam and just the job ID

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, beam

We have a GCP Dataflow project which requires us to cancel a running Dataflow job.

All we have at the time of cancellation is the Job ID.

From other posts on Stackoverflow, I learned we can cancel a job using something like this:

```
PipelineResult pipelineResult = pipeline.run();
result.cancel();
```

However, we don't store the pipelineResult when we create it.

The PipelineResult is just a DataflowPipelineJob. I am wondering if there are any ways I can retrieve a DataflowPipelineJob using its job and cancel it. Something like:

```
DataflowPipelineJob job = <Get DataflowPipelineJob using Job ID>;
job.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked upon the same [inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60872140/19378826) and the solution uses the Dofn interface, It is mentioned that it is within the [Dofn Process Element](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.ProcessElement.html) method.